# rollapply in datatable to calculate sums returns NAs

Tags: r, datatable, zoo

I would like to calculate rolling sums in R. I am using this code to create a data table TT:

```
TT <- data.table(ID=c(rep(100,9),rep(200,6)),date=seq(as.Date("1958-04-25"),as.Date("1958-05-9"),by="days"),
             output=c(5,8,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,13,2,14,12,14,14,NA))
```

Here I try to calculate the rolling sums, but the result is only NAs, even though in the first case (ID), the length should be > 7.

```
TT[,XX :=
 ifelse(length(output) >= 7,
        rollapply(output, 7, sum, na.rm = TRUE,align = "right",fill = NA_real_),
        rep(NA_real_,length(output))),by=ID]

TT[,length(output),by=ID]
```

What I want to do is calculate rolling sums with a window of 7, if possible, per ID. If not possible (i.e. not enough rows) per ID, I just want to have NAs. I am also open to other solutions.

Comment: The development version of zoo can handle series that are shorter than the `width=` argument.  `install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org");  TT[, XX := rollapplyr(output, 7, sum, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA_real_), by = ID]`

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse`. `ifelse(test, yes, no)` returns a value with the same shape as `test`, the mode of the result may depend on the value of `test`.

```
TT[, XX := if(length(output) >= 7) rollapply(output, 7, sum, na.rm = TRUE, align = "right", fill = NA_real_) else rep(NA_real_, length(output)), by = ID]

     ID       date output XX
 1: 100 1958-04-25      5 NA
 2: 100 1958-04-26      8 NA
 3: 100 1958-04-27     NA NA
 4: 100 1958-04-28      6 NA
 5: 100 1958-04-29      7 NA
 6: 100 1958-04-30      8 NA
 7: 100 1958-05-01     NA 34
 8: 100 1958-05-02     12 41
 9: 100 1958-05-03     13 46
10: 200 1958-05-04      2 NA
11: 200 1958-05-05     14 NA
12: 200 1958-05-06     12 NA
13: 200 1958-05-07     14 NA
14: 200 1958-05-08     14 NA
15: 200 1958-05-09     NA NA
```